# Running multiple hidden services in nginx

Tags: onion-services, help, network-configuration

I would like to setup 3 hidden services on the same computer with nginx.

My torrc looks like this:

```
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor  
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/   
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80   

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service1/  
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8081  

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service2/  
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8082
```

I have 3 files in /etc/nginx/sites-available:

- hidden_service
- hidden_service1
- hidden_service2

### hidden_service:

```
server{  
listen  127.0.0.1:80;  

root /var/www/hidden_service/;  
index index.html index.htm;  
server_name xxxxx.onion;  
}
```

### hidden_service1:

```
server{  
listen  127.0.0.1:8081;  

root /var/www/hidden_service/;  
index index.html index.htm; 
server_name yyyyy.onion;  
}
```

### hidden_service2:

```
server{  
listen  127.0.0.1:8082;  

root /var/www/hidden_service/;  
index index.html index.htm;  
server_name zzzzz.onion;  
}
```

Symbolic links are created between sites-available and sites-enabled.

The first hidden_service is working.But the other two are not connecting.
I tried with different port number and tried with the same port number but no luck.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: The first entry in your Nginx config file seems to be listening to port 80 (`listen 127.0.0.1:80;`), which is the virtual port specified for all services in the `torrc` file. Have you tried changing this? (e.g.) Change the three target ports in the `torrc` to 8081, 8082, 8083 (but keep the virtual port as 80 for each of them), then change the Nginx config to `listen 127.0.0.1:8081`, `listen 127.0.0.1:8082`, `listen 127.0.0.1:83`. At the minute, the first entry in the Nginx config is catching everything because they all use the same virtual port. (I _think_... )

Answer (score 1):

You can not listen on the same port multiple times.

There are 2 possibilities:

If you want your HSs to listen on different ports, then you should change your `HiddenServicePort` directives so they use different port numbers. (Like Richard Horrocks suggests in his comment.)

If you want them all on the same port, then you should have only one `HiddenServicePort` directive, and configure your web server to use virtual servers so that it hits the document root based on the server name in the request.